# html + javascript scroll detection not working

Tags: javascript, html, onscroll

I cannot seem to get scroll event to work for this layout. I am stuck and I was wondering if you guys can help me out. What I am trying to do is to detect when the content div, which has id="myContent", is scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>    

    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
        console.log("scrollFunction");
    }
    
    console.log(document.getElementById("myContent")); //dont know why it cannot find this arrrgghhh !!!

</script>
    
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;">

    <!--container-->
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;">
            
        <!--header-->       
        <div style="border: 1px solid green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 75px;
            top: 0;
            position: sticky;
            margin: 0 auto;
            align-items: center;"> 
        </div>
        
        <!--content-->
        <div id="myContent" 
            onscroll="scrollFunction();"            
            style="border: 1px solid blue; 
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;">   
                
            <!--content 1-->                    
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;">
            
            </div>          
        </div>
        
        <!--footer-->
        <div style="border: 1px solid pink;     
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 0 auto;">   
        </div>          
    </div>  
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: `window.onscroll = scrollFunction`

Comment: @zer00ne really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that currently the vertical scrollbar does not appear on the `div` that has the `onscroll` listener defined but on its parent. In order to see the scrollbar on that div, you must explicitly define its `height` together with `overflow-y: auto`. Make sure also to define `overflow: hidden` on the parent `div`.

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>    

    window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

    function scrollFunction() {
        console.log("scrollFunction");
    }
    
    console.log(document.getElementById("myContent")); //dont know why it cannot find this arrrgghhh !!!

</script>
    
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;">

    <!--container-->
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;">
            
        <!--header-->       
        <div style="border: 1px solid green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 75px;
            top: 0;
            position: sticky;
            margin: 0 auto;
            align-items: center;"> 
        </div>
        
        <!--content-->
        <div id="myContent" 
            onscroll="scrollFunction();"            
            style="border: 1px solid blue; 
                background-color: gray;
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;">   
                
            <!--content 1-->                    
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;">
            
            </div>          
        </div>
        
        <!--footer-->
        <div style="border: 1px solid pink;     
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 0 auto;">   
        </div>          
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Hi uminder tks for you answer . it worked ! I was wondering if there is a way for the scroll to appear throughout the entire page instead of only after the header div? 

tks in advance

Comment: @dnd: yes, this is basically what you initially had. In that case, you should define the onscroll listener on one a parent div.